# Why does my binary search algorithm WORK brilliantly, even though it absolutely shouldn't?

Tags: dart, binary-search

So the deal is this, I written the following code,
and after a while i realized that the line

```
int mid = (low + high);
```

Should be this instead:

```
int mid = (low + high) ~/ 2;
```

Much to my surprise and confusion, the initial code works absolutely fine, giving expected results no matter how much I change or tamper the searched in array.
Can anyone please explain where is ( or isnt ) an error because it drives me crazy.
Thanks,
Full code:

```
void main() {
  var ourArray = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 23, 34, 55];
  print(binarySearch(ourArray, 55));
}

binarySearch(var inputArray, int searchedItem) {
  int low = 0;
  int high = inputArray.length - 1;
  while (low <= high) {
    int mid = (low + high);
    if (inputArray[mid] == searchedItem) {
      return "Index of your element: $mid";
    } else if (inputArray[mid] > searchedItem) {
      high = mid - 1;
    } else {
      low = mid + 1;
    }
  }
  return "Element you are searching for does not exist.";
}
```

Comment: I believe this is now just a normal search since you always put the mid at the end of the array. The complexity of this is O(n).

Comment: "giving expected results" binary search isn't about the results, it's about how efficiently they are reached. Walking the array one element at a time also gives the expected results, after all. But that doesn't make it a binary search.

Comment: Print/output/log the value of `mid` inside the loop to see what is going on - both in which positions are checked and how many comparisons are made.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan thank you! Now when I think about it's obvious. So the thing still works as expected in terms of output however does it magnitude times slower than it should - what is not possible to detect working on such a small arrays, right?

Comment: You can count the number of comparisons or the iterations of the while loop, increase the array size or (and this may be the easiest option) artificially delay the execution of the function e.g. by introducing `sleep(new Duration(seconds: 1));` in the while loop. Then you'll notice the difference  in efficiency "hands-on" if you will between a correctly and incorrectly implemented solution.

Comment: @Mushroomator yes I actually realized that shortly after posting and first comment lmao ;)